# How to set Intellij to alert when there is no "this" for instance variable

Tags: java, intellij-idea

As the title says, how do I set IntelliJ to warn me when there is no this when accessing instance variables.

I know in Eclipse you could set this but I'm not sure how to do that in IntelliJ.

For example

private String field1

field1 << I should be this.field1 instead.

Comment: Why?  It's not always necessary; certainly not at declaration time.

Comment: It's just a code quality within the team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable warnings about accessing fields and methods not qualified with `this` in IntelliJ, enable the following code inspections:

1. On the main menu, choose **File | Settings**, or press **Ctrl+Alt+S**
2. In the settings dialog, choose **Project Settings | Inspections**
3. Check one or both of the following:

   - **Instance field access not qualified with 'this'**
   - **Instance method call not qualified with 'this'**